# How fix cannot read property of undefined?

Tags: json, typescript

I'm trying to retrieve some data from an API at the loading of the page. Data is well retrieved, but, I always get the error cannot read property `familles` of undefined in my HTML, even if I check if `familles` exists.

I have tried to load the data from an Observable and also from an ActivatedRoute snapshot. 
When I load it from the Observable, it works, but it returns me an error message.
When I load it from the ActivatedRoute snapshot, it just doesn't work

Here is the function `getFamilles` which retrieve data from an API :

```
getFamilles(){
    this.serviceFam.getAllFamilles()
      .subscribe(data => {
        this.listeFamilles = data;
      }, err => {
        console.log(err);
      });
  }
```

Here, the constructor of my component, where I call the function :

```
constructor(private serviceFam:FamillesService private route: ActivatedRoute) {
    this.getFamilles();
}
```

And there is my HTML :

```
<table *ngIf="listeFamilles">
  <tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let f of listeFamilles._embedded.familles">
      <th style="vertical-align: middle; padding-left: 10px;">{{ f.nom }}</th>
      <td  id="{{f.nom}}"  style="vertical-align: top;"></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Here is my function getAllFamilles from my service :

```
public getAllFamilles(){
    return this.httpClient.get(this.host+"/listFamilles");
  }
```

And here is how looks my JSON array coming from my API :

```
_embedded: {
familles: [
{
id: 1,
nom: "ARRIEL1",
couleur: "32cd32",
_links: {
self: {
href: "http://localhost:8080/familles/1"
},
famille: {
href: "http://localhost:8080/familles/1{?projection}",
templated: true
},
variantes: {
href: "http://localhost:8080/familles/1/variantes"
},
tempsgammes: {
href: "http://localhost:8080/familles/1/tempsgammes"
}
}
},
{
id: 2,
nom: "ARRIEL2",
couleur: "2b78e4",
_links: {
self: {
href: "http://localhost:8080/familles/2"
},
famille: {
href: "http://localhost:8080/familles/2{?projection}",
templated: true
},
variantes: {
href: "http://localhost:8080/familles/2/variantes"
},
tempsgammes: {
href: "http://localhost:8080/familles/2/tempsgammes"
}
}
}
```

Comment: So, what is `_embedded`? Should it be returned from your service? Looks like it's undefined.

Comment: `listeFamilles` probably doesn't contain a property called `_embedded`

Comment: _embedded is in my JSON array that i get from my API (with spring).

Comment: That isn't a valid JSON format. Validate it here: https://jsonlint.com/

Comment: Ok, so I have modified my JSON and now I have another error, which is : Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.

Comment: Have you changed any other code?